# gitignore in PHPStorm

Tags: php, git, phpstorm

I create a .gitignore file and add two folders.

But when I click "commit directory" in PHPStorm my folders are always in my commit changes.

```
magento/media/
magento/var/
```

[image]

What is going wrong?

In Terminal it works great

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, certain files *inside* those directories were already added to version control before the directories were added to `.gitignore`; note that the files listed as ignored in the command line and the ones being modified in the UI are not the same. You can remove them from source control (but not your working dir) with `git rm --cached`. Note that this will remove the file in *other* people's working directories when they do a `git pull`.